# How to relay the sum of each nested list to the next one?

Tags: python, list

My input is this list :

```
my_list = [[3, 4, -1], [0, 1], [-2], [7, 5, 8]]
```

I need to sum the nested list `i` and pad it to the right of the list `i+1`, it's like a relay course.

I have to mention that the original list should be untouched and I'm not allowed to copy it.

```
wanted = [[3, 4, -1], [0, 1, 6], [-2, 7], [7, 5, 8, 5]]
```

I tried the code below but I got a list with more elements than my original one :

```
from itertools import pairwise

wanted = []

for left, right in pairwise(my_list):
    wanted.extend([left, right + [sum(left)]])
    
print(wanted)
[[3, 4, -1], [0, 1, 6], [0, 1], [-2, 1], [-2], [7, 5, 8, -2]]
```

Can you guys explain what's happening please or suggest another solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```py
from itertools import accumulate

my_list = [[3, 4, -1], [0, 1], [-2], [7, 5, 8]]

print(list(accumulate(my_list, lambda l1, l2: [*l2, sum(l1)])))
```

Prints:

```
[[3, 4, -1], [0, 1, 6], [-2, 7], [7, 5, 8, 5]]
```

---

EDIT: As @KellyBundy pointed in the comments, the first element in the list is shared. So if it's a problem, make a copy from it e.g.:

```
accumulate([my_list[0][:], *my_list[1:]], lambda l1, l2: [*l2, sum(l1)])
```

Comment: Feels a bit dangerous to share the first inner list. [Demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY9LCsIwEIb3OcXsmkgqbVUsgicJQWIfNJAXaYr0LG660QO58zZabRDczD-Lfz7mu97dGDprpuk2hDYtn4_WWw0yND5Yq3qQ2lkfQFTVoAclQoOQHk9K9gGOwNiGwpZCmnMKLKPwybSY557CjkLJOUKmucSLOfAPhhcWBSX0uRag8vdaHICtVEGhHzRWOeGEIOS8NAFHFIlfsIyvhXONqXFiOzA2If_Vr9kiGEVf).

Comment: @KellyBundy Good catch... if that's a problem, one can make copy from first sublist. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I hope it's not a problem, the original solution is so pretty. The new solution not so much, and it would crash if my_list were empty.

Comment: @KellyBundy One can use `accumulate(map(list.copy, my_list), lambda l1, l2: [*l2, sum(l1)])`, but that will make copy of each sublist. Better to check if the original list isn't empty

Answer (score 3):

List comp:

```py
new_list = [
    lst
    for add in [[]]
    for lst in my_list
    for lst in [lst + add]
    for add in [[sum(lst)]]
]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuha3GHlyK-NzMotLFGwVoqONdRRMdBR0DWN1FKINdBTAtK4RiDTXUTDVUbCIjeUqT8wrSU3BqlxHwQyiQ0fBHEkTkATq48pLLYfbxKUABDnFJWA6Lb9IITElRSEzD2gmUCVMDCgPEoM6EF04GkRrgzTGYppSXJqrAZTXBJoGtLmgKDOvRANmvyYaX8HWVgHiKU1IoEDDBhZGAA)

Comment: This is a very advanced form of comprehension and also counterintuitive because on my machine your solution is >1.5 faster than @AndrejKesely approach even though you're using four loops. That's amazing, thanks Kelly Bundy!

Comment: @VERBOSE It's actually just one real loop, the last two that look like loops are simple assignments (in CPython since version 3.9).

Comment: To reply to your first comment, it's counterintuitive to me because I actually expected it to be slower, given that you're using four nested loops. And regarding the second one, this is a novelty to me to be honest!. This is the second time you've answered one of my questions and honestly you give off some very strong Python vibes. Keep up the good work!

Comment: @VERBOSE It's the first optimization mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations).

Comment: @KellyBundy: I've fallen in love with these constructs since you showed them to me.

Answer (score 2):

```py
def relay(l: list[list[int]]):
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        l[i].append(sum(l[i - 1]))
    return my_list

my_list = [[3, 4, -1], [0, 1], [-2], [7, 5, 8]]

print(relay(my_list))
```

This will produce your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your `pairwise` method this way:

```py
from itertools import pairwise
from copy import deepcopy

my_list = [[3, 4, -1], [0, 1], [-2], [7, 5, 8]]
new_list = deepcopy(my_list)

for lst_a, lst_b in pairwise(new_list):
    lst_b.append(sum(lst_a))

print(new_list)
```

Or you can try this:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

my_list = [[3, 4, -1], [0, 1], [-2], [7, 5, 8]]
new_list = deepcopy(my_list)

for i in range(len(new_list) - 1):
    new_list[i + 1].append(sum(new_list[i]))

print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[[3, 4, -1], [0, 1, 6], [-2, 7], [7, 5, 8, 5]]
```

Comment: Proabably should have used neither give `the original list should be untouched and I'm not allowed to copy it.` (which may have been added to the question after you started).

Answer (score 1):

I tried a little bit and was able to write something like this, I hope it helps:

```
my_list = [[3, 4, -1], [0, 1], [-2], [7, 5, 8]]

length = len(my_list)

wanted = []
for i in range(0,length):    # create new 2d list
    wanted.append([])

prev_total = 0    # store row_total for next iteration
row_total = 0

for i in range(0,length):
    prev_total = row_total
    row_total = 0
    for j in range(0,len(my_list[i])):
        wanted[i].append(my_list[i][j])
        row_total += my_list[i][j]

    if i != 0:
        wanted[i].append(prev_total)
        row_total += prev_total

print(wanted)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I just had to add my own list comprehension take to the other answers:

```
from itertools import accumulate
[sublist + ([s] if s is not None else []) for sublist, s in zip(my_list, [None, *accumulate(map(sum, my_list))])]
```

Note: `([s] if s is not None else [])` can be "shortened" to `[s] * (s is not None)` .

Comment: Gives wrong results, as you're not including the appended sums in the next sums.

Comment: Oh you're right! I should have compared my return to the others... Fixed now, thanks for chastising me ;)

Comment: You could slap an `accumulate()` around the sums of the original lists. I actually considered that previously but I didn't see a nice way to use it and suspect it's more efficient to sum the extended lists.

Comment: Ha, just saw that you already did exactly that.

Comment: My answer is probably less efficient and elegant than others, but as you know, I love to have "fun with comprehensions" ;)